# application insights exception rate for a specific exception

Tags: azure-application-insights

How can I set alert in application insights for a specific exception for e.g I want to get alerted in case of any outage in some areas of application even though application is available for e.g I want to get an alert if there are exception with the exception description like

1.) A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL SERVER.
2.) Timeout expired.
3.) Insufficient system storage

Answer (score 0):

At this time, we only support alerting on metrics. Alerting on counts of exceptions by type or "ProblemID" is high on our backlog though. Ability to alert on arbitrary text in the exception description or message/stack trace however, is further out. At this time, a potential work around may be to send metrics of substantially different outlier values (as compared to normal operation, base line values).